# Miners not mining designated area

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I cant figure out why my miners aren't mining an area I designated. I designated 2 areas before and they mined it out fine. Now I designated an area a bit deeper (maybe 30 tiles away) in and they arent going. However, if I designate an area closer (just 5 or so) they mine it. Why is that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! I thought the 2 stone length entrance halway to the new room was clear, but it still had to be mined.

Comment: Oh. Forgot. I apologize. Just your friendly neighborhood lurker reminding you to remember things. XD